# Javascript service worker notification timeout

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

This is the first time I am working with serviceworkers and notifications.

I am trying to show a notification at a specified time. I tried doing it in the service worker as follows:

```
function showNotification() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.registration.showNotification('Title', {
            body: 'body blablabla',
            badge: 'assets/images/logo.jpeg',
            icon: 'assets/images/logo.jpeg',
            renotify: false,
            requireInteraction: true,
            silent: false,
            vibrate: [200, 100, 200],
            dir: 'ltr',
            lang: 'en-US'
        });
    }, 3000);

}
```

I don't get any notifications if I try this. When I delete the setTimeout function, I do get a notification so I assume it has something to do with the timeout. Is there another way or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling the function in my Chrome JavaScript function (outside of the Service Worker) actually works in my case, I tried it this way :

```
function showNotification() {
  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(registration => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        registration.showNotification('Title', {
            body: 'body blablabla',
            badge: '/images/icon-light.png',
            icon: '/images/icon-light.png',
            renotify: false,
            requireInteraction: true,
            silent: false,
            vibrate: [200, 100, 200],
            dir: 'ltr',
            lang: 'en-US'
        });
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

Calling `showNotification` from the SW works too, I just tried the following code along with the `Applications -> Service Workers -> Push` in the Chrome Devtools console button to send a Push notification and then display it after 3 seconds :

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  if (event.data) {
    console.log('This push event has data: ', event.data.text());
  } else {
    console.log('This push event has no data.');
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    self.registration.showNotification(
      'Title',
      {
        body: 'body blablabla',
        badge: '/images/icon-light.png',
        icon: '/images/icon-light.png',
        renotify: false,
        requireInteraction: true,
        silent: false,
        vibrate: [200, 100, 200],
        dir: 'ltr',
        lang: 'en-US'
      }
    ); 
  }, 3000);    
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this may fail unpredictably, as the browser may decide to kill a service worker to conserve resources. You need to use `waitUntil` to make sure the serviceworker stays alive until the timeout has fired. Even then, the browser may decide to kill the service worker in the middle of the timeout. The longer the waiting period, the greater the chances. And this is a good thing. Imagine every page you ever visited has a service worker, each of which keeps firing timeouts to send back some analytics.